# jquery data attribute selector

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I am trying select some divs where the data attribute x10 equals the variable Xmodule.  I have something wrong with the selector but I don't know what is wrong.

```
 //find data element that matched Xmodule and display either on or off class
 $('div[data-x10=Xmodule]').each(function(){
 if (XStatus ==="2")
    {element.removeClass('off').addClass('on');}
 else
    {element.removeClass('on').addClass('off');};
  });
```

Comment: Where are you getting `element` from ?

Comment: What ever you have should work http://jsfiddle.net/2wr75/. Can you show your html?

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/spF8z/. Is the problem that you should be using `$(this)` instead of `element`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

It should be `$('div[data-x10="Xmodule]"')`.

Value of attribute should be passed in quotes.

Comment: If the value is a single word, the quotes aren't necessary. Also, even if they were, the second `"` would need to be inside the `]`.